Finding weights for the Borda count to elect any given candidate
Suppose three candidates A, B, and C run for office and voters submit their preference orders. The typical Borda count awards 2 points for a first-place vote, 1 point for a second-place vote, and 0 points for a third-place vote. The winner of the election is the candidate with the most points. We might also adjust these weights and say, for example, that a first-place vote receives 5 points and a second-place vote receives 3 points.
To see that the winner of the election may depend on the chosen weights, consider the following preference orders of 6 voters:

1 voter's preference order is $A>C>B$
3 voters' preference order is $B>A>C$
2 voters' preference order is $C>A>B$

Then under the typical Borda count, Candidate A is the winner, followed by B and then C, but if we award 5 points for a first-place vote and 1 point for a second-place vote, the winner is then Candidate B, followed by C and then A. However, and this is approaching my question, with these preference orders it can be shown there is no way to adjust the Borda weights to get a win for Candidate C.
With this setup, here is my question:

Is there an example of a collection of preference orders of three candidates and three different Borda weightings so that no two of these weightings lead to the same winning candidate? In other words, can we find a collection of preference orders so that any of the three candidates could be the winner with appropriately constructed Borda weighting?

Note we can always assume that a third-place vote receives 0 points, because the winner is invariant under changing the weights by a constant amount (e.g. a Borda count with weights 6-5-4 will elect the same winner as one with weights 2-1-0).

Do the weights need to be whole numbers?

@WW1: Good question. No, not necessarily, but given Dan's first observation I'm not sure we gain much flexibility by considering weights that are not whole numbers. As Dan has done though, it might make it easier to think about the problem if a first-place vote is always worth 1 and a second-place vote is worth $x$, for some $x$ in $[0,1]$.


Note we can always assume that a third-place vote receives 0 points, because the winner is invariant under changing the weights by a constant amount (e.g. a Borda count with weights 6-5-4 will elect the same winner as one with weights 2-1-0).

Similarly, since multiplying the weights by any (positive) constant factor does not change the Borda winner, we can assume that the first-place vote receives $1$ point.  That just leaves the second-place score as a variable.  Let's call it $x$, and assume that $0 \le x \le 1$.
By brute-forcing the possible combinations with a computer, I've found that you need a minimum of 9 voters to allow any of the three candidates to win the election.  This happens with the ballot set:

4: A > B > C
3: C > B > A
2: C > A > B

(or any equivalent preference order that permutes the labelling of the three candidates)

A receives $4 + 2x$ Borda points.
B receives $7x$ Borda points.
C receives $5$ Borda points.

The three pairwise contests are:

A versus B.  A wins if $4 + 2x > 7x$ (IOW, $x < \frac{4}{5}$), B wins if $x > \frac{4}{5}$, and they tie if $x = \frac{4}{5}$.
A versus C.  A wins if $4 + 2x > 5$ ($x > \frac{1}{2}$), C wins if $x < \frac{1}{2}$, and they tie if $x = \frac{1}{2}$.
B versus C.  B wins if $7x > 5$ ($x > \frac{5}{7}$), C wins if $x < \frac{5}{7}$, and they tie if $x = \frac{5}{7}$.

Going through the range of possible values of $x$:

If $x < \frac{1}{2}$, the Borda ranking is $ C > A > B$.
If $x = \frac{1}{2}$, the Borda ranking is $A = C > B$.
If $\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{5}{7}$, the Borda ranking is $A > C > B$.
If $x = \frac{5}{7}$, the Borda ranking is $A > B = C$.
If $\frac{5}{7} < x < \frac{4}{5}$, the Borda ranking is $A > B > C$.
If $x = \frac{4}{5}$, the Borda ranking is $ A = B > C$.
If $x > \frac{4}{5}$, the Borda ranking is $B > A > C$.

Or, if you just care about the winner rather than the full ranking:

If $x < \frac{1}{2}$, then C wins.
If $x = \frac{1}{2}$, then there is a tie between A and C.
If $\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{4}{5}$, then A wins.
If $x = \frac{4}{5}$, then there is a tie between A and B.
If $x > \frac{4}{5}$, then B wins.


Thanks so much for this helpful response. Yes, I missed the scalar multiple invariance, which does simplify the approach as you've done here. Though this answer doesn't quite answer my question, and perhaps because my question wasn't clear enough. I'm not requiring that we start with the preference orders I gave as an example in my question. I'm asking can we find some collection of preference orders (perhaps with more than 6 voters) such that it is possible that any candidate could win under some choice of weightings.

@Jared: I see.  I found a different ballot set that satisfies your requirements.
